# How to set reactive locale in all Vue3 Components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I have following project structure (`index.vue`):

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <navbar></navbar>
    <social-media-bar></social-media-bar>
    <main>
      <home></home>
      <news></news>
      <vision></vision>
      <event-section></event-section>
      <artwork></artwork>
      <about></about>
      <donate></donate>
      <contact></contact>
      <partners></partners>
    </main>
    <footer-component></footer-component>
  </div>
</template>
```

I want to change the `app-language` from inside `navbar.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <fa class="icon-locale" @click="toggleLocale" :icon="[ 'fa', 'language' ]" size="2x"></fa>
    <div class="locale-menu" :class="{ locale__open: isActiveLocale }">
      <p @click="toggleLocale(); setLocale('en');">en</p>
      <p @click="toggleLocale(); setLocale('de');">de</p>
      <p @click="toggleLocale(); setLocale('ar');">ar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {ref} from "vue";
import {createI18n} from 'vue-i18n';

const isActiveLocale = ref(false);
const toggleLocale = () => {
    isActiveLocale.value = !isActiveLocale.value;
}
const i18n = createI18n({});
const setLocale = (locale) => {
    i18n.global.locale = locale
};
</script>
```

Basically this opens a `locale menu` with `en, de, ar` locales which start an `@click` event that changes `i18n.global.locale` accordingly.

I need to set the newly set `i18n.global.locale` in the `home` component.

**`home.vue`**:

```
<template>
  <section id="home" class="home">
    <h2>{{ state.heading[state.locale] }}</h2>
  </section>
</template>


<script setup>
import {reactive} from 'vue';
import {useI18n} from 'vue-i18n';

const {locale} = useI18n()
const loc = locale.value.substring(0, 2)

const state = reactive({
    locale: loc
})
</script>
```

What I want is to get the newly set `i18n.global.locale` from `navbar.vue` into `state.locale` in `home.vue` reactively. Since `navbar` and `home` are no `parent/child`, do I have to build an `EventBus` for this or is there a more elegant solution, maybe with the `i18n` library?

**Edit:**

This is the function, that is supposed to change `locale` globally but it only sets it inside `i18n` and it looks like the only reactivity possible with that is with `i18n`'s `messages`, which I am not using.

```
const setLocale = () => {
    i18n.global.locale = 'de'
    console.log(i18n.global.locale);
};
```

I need to change the locale string globally, so that I can use it in all components reactively.

Comment: You should setup `i18n` in external **js** file and export them so you can use it in any component and change locale like `this.$i18n.locale = newLocale`;

Comment: Reactive locale is not a feature that actual users require. It's not that hard to implement, but reloading the whole app to switch locale is OK too — because real users will only do it once (or twice, if your l10n sucks and they figure they'd better use the original version). Just saying, don't waste time on it.

Comment: @Touffy you're prolly right

Answer (score 1):

**i18n.js**

```js
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";

export const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: "en",
  messages: {
    en: {
      message: {
        language: "Language",
        hello: "hello world!"
      }
    },
    ja: {
      message: {
        language: "言語",
        hello: "こんにちは、世界！"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**main.js**

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import { i18n } from "./i18n";

createApp(App).use(i18n).mount("#app");
```

**App.vue**

```js
<template>
  <button @click="switch">switch to ja</button>
  <p>{{ $t("message.hello") }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    switch() {
      // $i18n is reactively
      this.$i18n.locale = "ja";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement that. May I ask why you create two instances of Vue, one for `app` and a global(?) one?

Comment: Yeah, that's my fault, I will fix

Comment: I've made your approach work but there has been no change. I can set the `i18n.global.locale` but that only enables me to use `i18n`'s `messages` module, which I am not using. I just need to set a `locale string` (`de` for example) in all my components

Answer (score 0):

I found a super easy way to pass around variables between components in `vue` with `sessionStorage`. Just define:

```
sessionStorage.whatever = 'whateverYouWant'
```

and you can use `sessionStorage.whatever` in all your components. Other than `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` will reset, when the browser/tab is closed.
I am using it to pass around the selected `locale`.